# Google Analytics API V3 - Authorization API KEY (JAVA)

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I need to retrieve data from Google Analytics programatically in order to generate some reports, so OAuth 2.0 is not an option since it asks for user authorization..
Is there a way to retrieve data from GA API v3, using the API KEY ?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user must be authenticated to grant your application access to his data. This applies to any use case.

You can certainly use OAuth 2.0. Google offers the possibility to obtain an access token, which can be used by your application to access user data. In this case, the user only needs to be authorized once.

See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi for more info about accessing Google API's with an application using OAuth 2.0.